# Migrating email accounts from FirstClass to Exchange, selectively

Tags: exchange-2007

I am moving about 500 users from FirstClass to Exchange; however, we cannot move everyone at once and would like to do so in waves of 100 users. Is there a way to route mail to different servers based on email alias?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your Exchange Server to send mails to a "smarthost" if there is no mailbox with the email address in your exchange organization.

you have to set the accepted-domain to "InternalRelay"

[Here](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/planning-architecture/exchange-2007-smtp-namespace-sharing-different-relay-domain-types.html) is a article that describes the necessary steps

Comment: This question might also help you out: http://serverfault.com/questions/108815/setting-up-two-exchange-servers-to-receive-mail-on-their-old-domains-while-sendin/110422#110422